# Delete CDP Connector

Tags: api, data

We are trying to update the schema of a CDP connector but it throws an error. When we added the schema to a new connector it worked as expected. However, we need the name of the first connector and would like to delete it to create a new one with the correct schema. Is this possible? We cannot find any docs or guides on deleting a connector.

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like they are adding it to the UI in October release... In mean time you have to contact them to get it deleted